# "Unbound" variables in clojure functions

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a function to parse out IRC RFC2813 messages into their constituent parts. This consists of two functions, one to split the message via regex, and another to modify the return to handle certain special cases.

```
(let [test-privmsg ":m@m.net PRIVMSG #mychannel :Hiya, buddy."])

(defn ircMessageToMap [arg]
  "Convert an IRC message to a map based on a regex"
  (println (str "IRCMapifying " arg))
  (zipmap [:raw :prefix :type :destination :message]
          (re-matches #"^(?:[:](\S+) )?(\S+)(?: (?!:)(.+?))?(?: [:](.+))?$"
                      arg
                      )
          )
  )

(defn stringToIRCMessage [arg]
   "Parses a string as an IRC protocol message, returning a map"
     (let [r (doall (ircMesgToMap arg))])
     (println (str "Back from the wizard with " r))
     (cond
       ;Reformat PING messages to work around regex shortcomings
       (= (get r :prefix) "PING") (do
                                    (assoc r :type (get r :prefix))
                                    (assoc r :prefix nil)
                                  )
       ;Other special cases here
       :else r)
  )
```

The problem I'm running into is that the `stringToIRCMessage` function doesn't appear to be realizing the return value of ircMesgToMap. If I evaluate `(stringToIRCMessage test-privmsg)`, the `println` statement gives me:

`Back from the wizard with Unbound: #'irc1.core/r`

..but the "IRCMapifying" result from `ircMessageToMap` appears on the console beforehand indicating that it was evaluated correctly.

The `doall` was an attempt to force the result to be realized in the middle of the function - it had no effect.

How should I rewrite this `stringToIRCMessage` function to get the `r` variable usable?

Comment: You will also have to fix your `(do (assoc ...) (assoc ...))`, since the first of these has no effect. Remember that Clojure values are immutable, and that `(g (f x))` is very different from `(do (f x) (g x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parens are wrong in your `let` statement.

Should look like this:

```
  (let [r (doall (ircMesgToMap arg)) ]
     (println (str "Back from the wizard with " r))
     (cond
       ;Reformat PING messages to work around regex shortcomings
       (= (get r :prefix) "PING") (do
                                    (assoc r :type (get r :prefix))
                                    (assoc r :prefix nil)
                                  )
       ;Other special cases here
       :else r))
```

Comment: I need to have the entire rest of the function under the `let` block?

Comment: Only the part that cares about the value `r`.  It is "lexically scoped" just like in Java, C, etc (i.e. it is a "local variable" that doesn't exist, i.e. is "unbound", outside of the block)

Comment: Aha. I was under the assumption that the form by itself in the function bound it to the scope of the function.